# In the last post I have written about... or "I wrote about"?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

Inspired by a lang-8 text I've been proofreading:

> In the last post **I have written** about my first summer internship.

I know that it is a no-no to use the Present Perfect with a specific time expression:

> On 12 May 2014 I have written about.. (ERROR: must use "I wrote")

Do constructions like "the last letter" or "the last post" qualify as something akin to specific time expressions? I mean, do they unequivocally put the event in the "completed past"? Should we always substitute for:

> In the last post **I wrote** (not "I have written"!) about my first summer internship.

Comment: I don't know if it has to do with "time expressions" but it's definitely "I wrote".

Comment: @Catija - thanks for the comment, I've expanded my question to clarify my idea.

Comment: Maybe if you think of it as the same thing as "last week"... which is a specific time and follows a more similar structure as "in the last post"? Both of these constructions would require "I wrote".

Comment: @Catija - yes. I thought "in the last post" implies some specific and "completed" time period in the past.

Comment: A single post is indeed a discrete, completed event. In my last letter.... But one could say *In my latest posts, I've been asking about....*

Comment: @TRomano - a good point! Using 'posts' in the plural gives a feeling of continuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the **last post** or in the **last letter** is indeed a completed action in the past as in [**last week**](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html), and for this reason we cannot use the present perfect.

In this case the use of simple past is required.

Comment: +1. I removed "the" before "as in <strike>the</strike> last week" just to avoid confusion.  "In the last week, I *have received* four calls from telemarketers at dinner time."  "Last week" is discrete and complete; "in the last week" is a span that is proximate to the present.

Comment: Much obliged @TRomano!-:)